# How to upload image to other server

Tags: php

I'm using the code given in the link - https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/. The image is storing fine in the same server, however I need to store the image in different server. Is this possible using PHP?

I modified my codings but still my file is not transferable.

```
$ch = curl_init ("Source file’s complete url”);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
// Check if any error occured 
if(curl_errno($ch)) 
{ 
  $fp = fopen(“Destination file’s complete url”, 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
  fclose($fp);
}
curl_close ($ch);
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Have replaced source and destination url, but still no results, please help me..

Comment: Of course not, that would be a major security flaw if I could upload files to a different server, unauthenticated.

Comment: Okay so You mean there will be a security issue if we transfer the files from one server to other server

Comment: I mean it's not *possible* using `move_uploaded_files()`, for reasons of security. If it were possible, I could upload a script to your server and exploit it. You have to look into using an FTP protocol (for example, the `ftp_*` functions in PHP).

Comment: Thanks, so it is possible using ftp functions, any reference links, please....

Comment: Can someone guide me in this

Comment: Just check the manual https://www.php.net/ftp-connect

Comment: I have tried the curl function in php to transfer the files from one to other server but no results, can anyone guide me if any codings above are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);

Please refer this link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

Comment: This code I have added with all necessary values in my source server but am not getting any results.

Comment: I have tired the below coding also "<?php
$src = "http://sampledemos.online/android/uploads/1.jpeg";
$dest = "https://dev.kanchikart.in/android/" . basename($src);
file_put_contents($dest, file_get_contents($src));
?>" but files are not getting stored, anything i missed out.

Comment: Can you please try and follow this link using the method you prefer firstly (CURL). Its working for me. 
https://subinsb.com/upload-image-to-remote-server-with-php-curl-and-handling-file-in-remote-server/

Comment: Its not working for me :(, I have modified this part alone - curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '<span style="color: red;">https://dev.kanchikart.in/android/handle.php</span>') and in my destination server I have added handle.php file, anything I missed